# min value sql query

Tags: sql

I have a data with three columns as below:

```
lic_plt_id     qty     prod_qty
--------------------------------
123456         3        44556
345567         50       44556
098765         13       44556
```

result required is where qty is minimum with below detail.

```
lic_plt_id   qty   prod_qty
----------------------------
123456       3       44556
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Tablename
ORDER BY qty
```

this will order the table by qty and then selects the first one which is the lowest number.

Comment: does not gives result , error - ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement. Select TOP 1 * is exactly how should i Run ??? Table name is iinvd